# Populate an html table columwise with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a MySQL query that returns data using PHP.
My problem is that I need to populate my html table (with 3 columns) with the data returned by the query but the data should be populated Columnwise.
Like first the first column should be populated .. then the second and finally the third one.

Also I would like to know that is it possible to do so for an unlimited set of data?

[image]

Following the screen shot of the desired layout

Comment: you can implement `Data Binding`.

Comment: Oh, so the results are all the same column in your database?

Comment: Your description implies sorting which is not evidence from your example. Also, populating a table by column rather than row requires buffering of a variable amount of data - but you can get the same result without bufering by using 3 tables, or CSS - why is the single table a requirement? HTTP / HTML won't work with "an unlimited set of data" - do you mean a varable number of records?

Answer (score 0):

you can use while.

```
<table>
$sql=mysql_query("select * from table");

 while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {

    $x=$s["x"];
    <tr>
     <td ><?php echo $x; ?></td>
     <td ><?php echo $y; ?></td>
     <td ><?php echo $z; ?></td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: please explain your answer .. didn't get it

Comment: actually this is your answer. $sql is your data set and you can print unlimited row or column. you dont have to use <tr> tags.  just use <td> for unlimited column.

Answer (score 0):

guybennet's answer is correct but if you want it to work for an unlimited amount of columns you could do this: (I also threw in some column headers for readability)

```
echo '<table>';
$counter = 0;
$result = mysql_query("select * from table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $counter++;
    if($counter == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            echo "<th>$key</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        echo "<td>$val</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Also of course you should use mysqli or PDO I'm just showing a quick example.

Comment: You need to provide more info than a screenshot. Maybe show some code or show the structure of your database table.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about how it's organized, you can try something like this:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>\n";
    $i++;
    if($i==3)
    {
        echo "</tr>\n<tr>";
        $i=0;
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest putting it all into an array and then putting it into the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

$itemsAmount = count($data);
$ceilAmount = ($itemsAmount - $itemsAmount % 3) / 3;
$lastAmount =  $itemsAmount % 3;
$firstArray = array_slice($data, 0, $itemsAmount);
$secondArray = array_slice($data, 0, $itemsAmount*2);
$thirdArray = array_slice($data, 0, $lastAmount);

$output = "<table>";

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $firstArray[$key][0] . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $secondArray[$key][0] . "</td>";
    if (empty($thirdArray[$key])) {
        $str = '';
    } else {
        $str = $thirdArray[$key][0];
    }
    $output .= "<td>" . $str . "</td>";
    $output .= "</tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";

echo $output;
```

Comment: its printing array instead of data :O

Comment: Sorry for that. Modified my answer - forgot about indexes

Comment: its showing same row i.e event_title 3 times in Ist 2 rows and then 2 times in subsequent rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all the results returned, then print them as you won't print in order:

First get an array with all the results

```
<?php
 $sql= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
 $num= mysql_affected_rows($sql);
 $items = array();
 $i=0;
 while($item=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $items[++$i]=$item['data'];
 }
```

Now start printing

```
 int $num_rows;
 $num_rows=$num%3;
 echo '<table>';
 for ($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($j=0;$j<2,$j++){
   $n=$i+1+($j*$num_rows);
   if($items[$n]!==null)
   echo '<td>'.$items[$n].'</td>';
   else
    echo '<td></td>';
  }echo '</tr>';

 }echo'</table>';
 ?>
```

Comment: I have already fixed some, would you let me know what are the errors. As well the algorithm should work, you can fix the minor syntax errors.